# Select Max customer ID in Hive

Tags: hive, conditional-statements, max

[image]

I want to select the max customer ID from the same account_number.

```
select max (customer_ID),account_number
from Account
group by account_number
having account_number ='30010258'
```

The result is

[image]

I expect result is

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select max (int(customer_ID)),account_number
from Account
group by account_number
having account_number ='30010258'

Answer (score 0):

Use a `where` clause instead of `having`.

Note: if account_number is of type int then remove the quotes around 30010258.If the datatype for customer_ID is string then you will have to cast it to int.

```
select max (customer_ID),account_number
from Account
where account_number ='30010258'
group by account_number
```

Comment: the easy way is select max(int(Customer_ID))